# Grid style layout

Tags: html, css

I basically want to use css and html to position elements such that they take up whatever space they fit. So I have a grid-like structure, with elements stacked up nicely. The problem is that I can't get the small boxes to fill up beside the large box. e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/9pk4J/1/

HTML:

```
<section id="cubes">
  <div>
          <article class="large"></article>
        </div>
  <div>
          <article></article>
        </div>
        <div>
          <article></article>
        </div>
        <div>
          <article></article>
        </div>
        <div>
          <article></article>
        </div>
        <div>
          <article></article>
        </div>
        <div>
          <article></article>
        </div>
        <div>
          <article></article>
        </div>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
#cubes {
font-size:0;
position: absolute;
    max-width:670px;
}
#cubes div {
display:inline-block;
padding:3px;
}
#cubes div article.large {
cursor:pointer;
display:inline-block;
height:300px;
width:492px;
background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
overflow:hidden;
}
#cubes div article {
cursor:pointer;
display:inline-block;
height:150px;
width:160px;
background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
overflow:hidden;
}
```

I realize there are methods where I could name specific elements and use absolute positioning to put them in place, but ideally I would like to have them fit vertically and horizontally into place using just css and html.

Comment: Have you looked into http://masonry.desandro.com/?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @Luis that Masonry is probably a better bet, but if you can fix the width and the sizes of the boxes, you can accomplish this with straight CSS. If you're always going to have 1 large box first, then several small ones, just `float:left` on all your divs and you're good to go. Shown here:

http://jsfiddle.net/9pk4J/2/

Answer (score 1):

I would recomend using a plug in for that, `Masonry` it's the name, and you can check its page.

There is a version with Jquery and other one with only CSS ('vanilla version')

Here is a live demo with your previous fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/9pk4J/5/

**html Markup**

```
<section id="cubes">
    <div class="box">
        <article class="large"></article>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <article></article>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <article></article>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <article></article>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <article></article>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <article></article>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <article></article>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <article></article>
    </div>
</section>
```

**js Markup**

```
$('#cubes').masonry({
    itemSelector: '.box',
    columnWidth: 100,
    isAnimated: true
});
```

[Jquery Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/)

[Vanilla Masonry](http://vanilla-masonry.desandro.com/)

Hope it helps!

Comment: That seems neat, but I don't like how cluttered the example they use is. It seems to me that something like Masonry would be better-used for items consisting of blocks of mostly-solid color (something akin to Metro, now that I think about it), as having busy blocks at uneven distributions can be disorienting to the eye and make an interface harder to use even if it looks pretty. (I'm referring to using multiple smaller blocks all at once; when it's only 2 or 3 large blocks, or just a flow down the page of 1~2 columns, it seems still a bit busy but easier to follow than the front-page one).

Comment: @JAB I agree, it could make your whole interface a mess, I guess it just depends on how they are going to use it...

Answer (score 0):

Well it *should* be possible with [CSS flexible boxes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes) but [browser support is not great](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) (IE10+ only for example), although Chrome and Firefox have good support for the model.

Using a [CSS flexbox builder](http://demo.agektmr.com/flexbox/), I managed to create a [small demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sK94m/1/) (only tested in Chrome 29) of how the boxes would be rendered but there are plenty of options to customise the output. Still, you might find that they boxes still don't flow correctly, but there's something to play nonetheless.

Sorry the code is a bit cluttered, I lifted it straight out of the builder page!

```
<div class="visual">
  <div class="box" ng-style="model | vendorPrefix" ng-class="{hover:hoverContainer}" style="-webkit-flex-flow: column wrap; -webkit-justify-content: flex-start; -webkit-align-content: flex-start; -webkit-align-items: flex-start;">
    <div class="ng-scope ng-binding" style="-webkit-order: 1; -webkit-flex: 0 1 auto; -webkit-align-self: auto; min-width: 150px; min-height: 150px;">A</div>
    <div class="ng-scope ng-binding" style="-webkit-order: 2; -webkit-flex: 0 0 50px; -webkit-align-self: auto; min-width: 50px; min-height: 50px;">B</div>
    <div class="ng-scope ng-binding" style="-webkit-order: 2; -webkit-flex: 0 0 50px; -webkit-align-self: auto; min-width: 50px; min-height: 50px;">C</div>
    <div class="ng-scope ng-binding" style="-webkit-order: 2; -webkit-flex: 0 0 50px; -webkit-align-self: baseline; min-width: 50px; min-height: 50px;">D</div>
    <div class="ng-scope ng-binding" style="-webkit-order: 2; -webkit-flex: 0 0 50px; -webkit-align-self: auto; min-width: 50px; min-height: 50px;">E</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think your example would be more easily examined if you separated the styling from the markup.